# Does $project allow to move all the sub-field of a given field in the document JSON to the upper level?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like this in MongoDB 4.2:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "timestamp" : ISODate(...),
    "data" : {
        "field1" : ... ,
        "field2" : ... ,
        ...
        "fieldN" : ...
}
```

where N can be quite large (~20 fields)

The `data` element is just boilerplate so I'd like to get rid of it and simplify my documents to this:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "timestamp" : ISODate(...),
    "field1" : ... ,
    "field2" : ... ,
    ...
    "fieldN" : ...
}
```

Using the aggregation framework I can do this with `$project` stage like this:

```
db.c.aggregate([
  {$project: {timestamp: 1, field1: "$data.field1", field2: "$data.field1", ..., fieldN: "$data.fieldN"}}
])
```

The problem of this solution is that `$project` value can be very large and the aggregation query long and confusing.

Is there any other better alternative? Does `$project` allow to move all the sub-field of a given field in the document JSON to the upper level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) along with [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT","$data"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AjHHk3YZbuP)